# Prevent duplicates from adding the datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to make an application that fetches the results from an already existing database, append it with a cvs file, and then push it back to the database with the appended records. The problem is I'm getting a lot of duplicates because of this.

For example lets say I have this in my database:

```
ID     NAME
 1     Jon
 2     Jason
 3     Adam
```

And my cvs would look like this:

```
ID     NAME
 1     Jon
 2     Jason
 3     Adam
 4     Eva
 5     Jack
```

Then I would get this in my datagridview:

```
ID     NAME
 1     Jon
 2     Jason
 3     Adam
 1     Jon
 2     Jason
 3     Adam
 4     Eva
 5     Jack
```

How can I prevent it from adding duplicates? I've already got something that removes duplicates from the cvs file but I have no idea how I can check if the records I get from the select statement are equal to the records from the cvs file.

Here's my code, _docentid is basically just ID like the example above and same goes for _docentnaam being NAME

```
               public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly List<string> _docentid = new List<string>();
    private readonly List<string> _docentnaam = new List<string>();

    #region Members

    private DataSet _myDataSet;

    #endregion

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    #region Properties

    public DataSet MyDataSet
    {
        get { return _myDataSet ?? (_myDataSet = new DataSet()); }
    }

    #endregion

    private void buttonGet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\Temp\exceltest.csv"));
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                if (line == null) continue;
                string[] values = line.Split(';');

                _docentid.Add(values[4]);
                _docentnaam.Add(values[5]);
            }

        SqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommand mySelectCommand = new SqlCommand
        {
            CommandText = "SELECT * FROM dbo.docent;",
            CommandType = CommandType.Text
        };

        myDataAdapter.SelectCommand = mySelectCommand;

        using (
            SqlConnection cnn =
                new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionPlain"].ConnectionString))
        {
            mySelectCommand.Connection = cnn;
            myDataAdapter.Fill(MyDataSet);
        }

        int incr = 1;
        foreach (string t in _docentnaam.Skip(1))
        {
            DataRow rw = MyDataSet.Tables[0].NewRow();
            rw["docentid"] = Convert.ToInt32(_docentid[incr]);
            rw["docentnaam"] = t;
            if (!MyDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Any(row => row["docentid"].Equals(rw["docentid"]) && row["docentnaam"].Equals(rw["docentnaam"])))
            incr++;
        }
        dataGridViewPersons.DataSource = MyDataSet.Tables[0];
    }
```

Comment: what defines a duplicate record?  The ID?  Combination of First and Last Name?  I'd read the CSV into its own DataTable and only add the data to the other after I perform that test.

Comment: when you read the data from the csv file then try to add it to the database, check to see that if each record exists before you add to the database.

Comment: @Plutonix A row with two exact the same values, it doesn't matter if the ID is the same since the table has ID defined as a primary key so I'll get an error regardless.